# How to remove decorator for new line

Tags: vscode-extensions

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function attachCleanLine(deco: vscode.TextEditorDecorationType) {
    vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(event => {
        const activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
        if (!activeEditor) {return;}

        const contentChange = event.contentChanges[0];
        if (contentChange.text === '\n') {
            let currentLine = activeEditor.selection.active.line;
            currentLine = currentLine + 1;
            let lineText = activeEditor.document.lineAt(currentLine).text;
            console.log(`Enter key pressed on line ${currentLine}, someVariable: ${lineText}`);

            const line = activeEditor.document.lineAt(currentLine);


            // HOWTO: remove decorator for the new line after return
            activeEditor.setDecorations(deco, []);
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is that when hitting enter, the decorator from the line moves down to new line. So I am trying to remove the decorator for this newline: